# Regex to check for a plus sign and digits

Tags: java, regex

I want to check a string contains a "+" and digits only:

```
public boolean checkPhoneNumberIsValid(String arg) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]").matcher(arg).find();
}
```

When I try "xxx", this correctly fails. When I try "+3531234567" it correcrtly passes. But when I try "+35312ccc34567" is incorrectly passes. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's incorrectly passes is because you are matching only a single digit after `+`. You need to match entire string till the end and check whether it has only digits. Try following regex:

```
\\+[0-9]+$
```

or

```
\\+\d+$
```

`+` at the end of the regex signifies: `Match one or more occurrence of [0-9]`.

See this: https://regex101.com/r/0ufZPi/1

```
+3245edsfv    //fail
+86569653386  //pass
+xxxx         //fail
+234fsvfb7890 //fail
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the `find` method finds a single substring match in your argument. I would recommend the `matches` methods which checks that the full string matches:

```
public boolean checkPhoneNumberIsValid(String arg) {
    return Pattern.matches("\\+[0-9]+", arg);
}
```

`[0-9]+` means one or more digits. You were missing the `+` so you were only matching a single digit at the beginning of the string using the `find` method.

You can also see the `Pattern.matches` method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

However, if you really want to use the `find` method you would have to use `"\\+[0-9]+$"` for the regular expression to force the `find` method to match the full string. `$` means that the end of the string must be there.

Additionally, if you are planning on calling `checkPhoneNumberIsValid` often you should precompile the regular expression as it is more efficient as stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
private static final Pattern PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]+");

public boolean checkPhoneNumberIsValid(String arg) {
    return PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX.matcher(arg).matches();
}
```

Comment: No need for the `^` and `$` anchors;  the `matches` method already requires that the input string match the entire pattern exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the info!